# My subtheme css is overriden by the parent theme. How to I reverse this?

Tags: theming

I have created a subtheme and for some reason the css I add in there to override the parent theme doesn't work. THe parent theme's css seems to be prioritized over my new stuff. Is there any way of weighting themes or ordering loading of themes?

Comment: I'm having the same issue -- did you ever solve it?

Comment: IIRC, it actually had something to do with my SASS/Compass syntax. It wasn't throwing up an error when compiling and Firefox was ignoring the broken CSS rule. Drupal was behaving as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'm encountering the same issue.  If I disable the css aggregation I can see that the reason is that my sub-theme's css stylesheet is being `@import`ed before the one(s) from the base theme, which means, of course, that the base theme's styles are overriding mine anywhere where I use the same selectors.  Which is crazy.  How is this not a problem for more people?  Is there something we're missing here?

**Edit:** sure, I can use `!important`, which is what I'm doing as a workaround (and presumably the OP @Nigel Waters could do the same?), but doesn't this rather defeat the purpose to some degree?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your selectors are off, make sure specificity is good. Use this:

[image]

Comment: Not sure what the screenshot is all about?

Comment: here's a link to the full article: http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

Comment: My selectors are not off. I have another subtheme on another site that easily overrides a parent theme. For some reason it doesn't work on this project.

Comment: actually this happen to me before too. last i remember it was due to incorrect css syntax. try wiping your entire subtheme css file and then just put in 1 css style that targets what you need to see if that took effect or not. (background:red) just to see if it overrides. if it does then it is indeed something wrong with your syntax. thats how i would debug this.

Comment: Also, if you check the element in a DOM inspector like Firebug, you can see the "Computed style" and pinpoint the exact line(s) that are applying the given CSS rules.

I had a similar issue, and it turned out the base theme's CSS was overriding my rules because theirs was more specific.

Comment: The css is copied verbatim from the parent theme and the parent theme is overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

It most likely has to do with the order the styles are loaded- the css loaded last overrides styles that come before.

To correct this, you could add a higher weight to your css if it's called through drupal_add_css.

```
drupal_add_css(
      '/path/to/css.css',
      array(
        'weight' => '9999',
      )
);
```

Another option is to override the parent theme's style by identically naming your stylesheet.

/parenttheme/css/style.css will not be used if /childtheme/css/style.css exists.

Comment: it's very definitely to do with the order the styles are loaded -- see my answer 1 hour before yours.  of course, we're talking here about subthemes, so neither of your suggestions constitute viable solutions to the given problem, unfortunately :(

Comment: Both of my solutions are viable. subthemes == childthemes. I've written both parent and child themes, and am very aware of their precedence and manipulation via .info or .php